# Cannot get location using GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm trying to get `latlong` using only GPS. If I use `NetworkManager` I'm getting location `latlong` but if use gps, `GPS_PROVIDER` I'm getting `null` location.

Please tell me how to get gps location using `GPS_PROVIDER`.

**Code.**

```
 public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            /*isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

*/
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                /*if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }*/
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * app.
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting DialogHelp Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting DialogHelp Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("location",location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());

        float bestAccuracy = -1f;
        if (location.getAccuracy() != 0.0f
                && (location.getAccuracy() < bestAccuracy) || bestAccuracy == -1f) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
        bestAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        Log.d("location",location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public float getAccurecy()
    {
        return location.getAccuracy();
    }

}
```

Comment: wait for sometimes it take time for getting location show toast on ... onLocationChanged method to acknowledge. location getting or not..

Answer (score 0):

```
 **FusedLocationProviderApi** 

    public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements
          LocationListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
Button btnFusedLocation;
TextView tvLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
String mLastUpdateTime;

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);

    btnFusedLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    btnFusedLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            updateUI();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    startLocationUpdates();
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
    if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        tvLocation.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
       }
     }
     }








  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LocationActivity"
android:background="#ffffa6c7">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/locationTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Location"
    android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffff1a7c"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="134dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```